# What is wrong with this MySQL query - declaring in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_wall BEFORE INSERT ON wall FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE x INT;
SET x = (SELECT count(*) FROM wall); 
IF x > 10 THEN
DELETE
FROM wall
ORDER BY DATE ASC 
LIMIT 1
END IF;
END&&

DELIMITER ;
```

Just nothing happens. I have no triggers show up in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps another `;` here

```
DELETE
FROM wall
ORDER BY DATE ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you used?

```
DELIMITER $$
```

Then the `;` will not matter to the end of the trigger.

At the end of the trigger put `END $$`

**EDIT**

```
END&&
```

should read

```
END $$
```

Comment: updated the OP, please have a look

Comment: In the case of END$$ I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF; END' at line 10

Comment: Oops - Space between the End and the $$

Comment: That didn't work. the error ended up being with the IF statement! i was missing a semicolon apparently.